# Pertaining to slushpool mining . What is the most lucrative way to vote ? Or does it matter

Tags: block

What is the most lucrative way to vote on slushpool? Or does it matter

Comment: Vote in what way?

Comment: It always depends on what the current vote is for. Your question can be improved with more details. Please see [how to ask](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for assistance.

Comment: What does vote even mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Voting doesn't affect earnings. Long before SegWit activated, the miners were voting, because it was about to choose Bitcoin's destiny: 40% of the network was voting for SegWit while the other 40% was voting for a block size increase.

The scaling debate is already over, so it doesn't have any effects, currently.

- Choose "Pool decides" if you're a big fan of Slush or Prusnak
- Choose "Bitcoin Core" if you're very thankful for what Core developers have brought to Bitcoin
- Choose "Not Voted" if you like neither, since Slush has always been supporting Core developers.